OpenAI APIConnectionError: Connection error
I consistently receive an openai.APIConnectionError: Connection error message when attempting to use the API, while working on a project with langchain and streamlit.
I have tried debugging it by following through all necessary details related to the error on the openai documentation page, but that could not help
Details:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 600, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vs_codes\astro_bot\bot.py", line 83, in <module>
    refined_query = query_refiner(conversation_string, query)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vs_codes\astro_bot\utils.py", line 36, in query_refiner
    response = client.completions.create(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\openai\_utils\_utils.py", line 277, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\openai\resources\completions.py", line 528, in create
    return self._post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1240, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 921, in request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 976, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1053, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 976, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1053, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\astro_bot\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 986, in _request
    raise APIConnectionError(request=request) from err
openai.APIConnectionError: Connection error.

        with st.spinner("typing..."):
            conversation_string = get_conversation_string()
            # st.code(conversation_string)
            refined_query = query_refiner(conversation_string, query)

def query_refiner(conversation, query):

    
    response = client.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    prompt=f"""Given the following user query and conversation log, formulate a question that would be the most relevant to provide the user with an answer from a knowledge base.\n\nCONVERSATION LOG: \n{conversation}\n\nQuery: {query}\n\nRefined Query:""",
    temperature=0.7,
    max_tokens=256,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0
    )
    return response['choices'][0]['text']

def get_conversation_string():
    conversation_string = ""
    for i in range(len(st.session_state['responses'])-1):
        
        conversation_string += "Human: "+st.session_state['requests'][i] + "\n"
        conversation_string += "Bot: "+ st.session_state['responses'][i+1] + "\n"
    return conversation_string```

